# facebook login issue when facebook is blocked from firewall using mac Address

Tags: angularjs, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using angular-facebook.js for facebook login. Its working fine in normal process ( when not blocked on firewall). But when facebook access is blocked from firewall, i am getting below error and nothing is loading in the page.

As per my knowledge, it is unable to call https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js so its returning my page HTML which causing the below error. How i can resolve this error?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.js:4640 Uncaught Error:[$injector:modulerr]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr p0=applicationApp&p1=E…20
```

Comment: you must unblock it in ur firewall or ask your admin to give access for your ip to access fb

Comment: it will work only for my ip then, i need solution when it is blocked because wherever facebook is blocked application will not work @SaEChowdary

Comment: yes.....if your pc has access  then the code will  works on the your system and if u try to run on some other's who doesn't   have access  it will give error